# Reading REST service parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Java REST API that looks like this:

```
GET /dashboard/group/{group}/class/{class}/view/{view_by}/utilizations
```

I want to write a client for it in Rails and also in Controller to access the values of its parameters, etc
So for example in `/dashboard/group/group_elite/class/middle_class/view/all/utilizations`

the values for parametrs `group, class and view` are `group_elite, middle_class and all`

My question is how can I access those paramters and their values?

Comment: It depends on your routes, if you have set it like `get '/dashboard/group/:group/class/:class/view/:view_by/utilizations`, you would have the following parameters: `params[:group], params[:class], params[:view_by]` but then, if you are parsing this URL, you have to make you own REgexp to detect the values of the params.

Comment: hmm a little confused now: Depends on the routes? but if it is a Java Service I am calling, then they don't have routes, right? so I should do RegEx to read those params?

Comment: Oh okay, that's why I thought on the first place. So you are like sending HTTP requests with your Rails server to another Java Service, right? If yes, then yes you would need a Regexp to read those params. Can you provide some examples (the trickiest you could have) of the URLs with parameters? I can help you write the Regexp if you need ;)

Comment: Thanks Sir, the one I posted above was actually a real one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay let's say you do your thing in the controller to construct the URL to query, then you can use this to "parse and get the params":

```
url = '/dashboard/group/{group}/class/{class}/view/{view_by}/utilizations'
ar = url.split('/')
params_to_check = [ :group, :class, :view ]
params_h = {}
params_to_check.each do |param|
  value_index = ar.index(param.to_s) + 1
  params_h[param] = ar[value_index] if ar[value_index].present?
end
```

There is actually no need for a Regexp here. (You can do a copy-paste in your console and run `puts params_h`, it should outputs what you want (hopefully!)

As you can see, **this code implies** that the parameter follows the attribute name: `/group/{value}`, not like `/group/smthing/{group}`

Comment: Thanks, take a look at this gem too, do you think we can utilize its methods to help parsing URLS? https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/

Comment: Hmm no, there is no need for this Gem, simply use the URI module if you want to parse your URL safely: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse (then you can access to several methods like `uri.path ; uri.query ; uri.host` etc)